# Process where you add an unused factor

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following process:

1. Choose a positive integer $x$.
2. Choose a *proper factor* $f$ of $x$ that hasn't been used before ($f \neq 1$ and $f \neq x$). If there is no such $f$ then terminate.
3. Set $x$  to $x+f$ and go to step 2.

For example, suppose we start with 4. 2 is a factor of 4, so we go to 6. We cannot reuse the factor 2, so we must use factor 3, going to 9. We cannot go any further in this case. If we started with 6, we could go to 8, 12, 18, 27, 30, 40, 60 and so on.

Is this process guaranteed to terminate or can it go on indefinitely? I don't know the answer and not sure where to begin.

UPDATE: starting from 6 I can reach over 2000 terms before reaching the limits of a Java Integer. It seems that this process can continue indefinitely, but I have no proof.

Comment: Your "algorithm" is not clear - why after 12 you do not use 3? After 30 not 5? Those are proper factors.

Comment: you can choose which factor to use.

Comment: I am thinking about the case where every time you pick the biggest factor. By starting at 1024 it seems to diverge( using computer), but I haven't been able to prove it. Very interesting question, where does it come from?

Comment: @grover I made up while going on a hike.

Comment: Just add half the previous value.

Comment: @Moti but what if that gives you an odd?

Comment: Divide by 3 and add.

Comment: Lol this is not the 3x+1 problem. You can't just divide by 3 and add.